# Read part of binary file in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to read the first 100 bytes from a binary file. I will then print them as hex. What is the most concise way to read them?

Answer (score -1):

My current implementation is:

```kotlin
FileInputStream(File("/path/to/file")).use { stream ->
  val buffer = ByteArray(100)
  stream.read(buffer)
  Log.d("EXAMPLE", buffer.joinToString(separator = " ") { "%02x".format(it) })
}
```